# @Html.ActionLink not Rendering as Expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this in my Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "User",
            "User/{username}/{action}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username = "*" }
        );
```

Then on my _Layout.cshtml I have this code:

```
            <ul id="menu">
            @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", new { controller = "User" }, new { username = Context.User.Identity.Name })</li>
            }


            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The thing is, it will render the link properly the first time it swings through here. (Link will be /User/rob/Home where "rob" is a username. If I navigate elsewhere on the page and then click back on my link, the link is rendered as /User/*/Home.  When I step through the code, Context.User.Identity.Name is correct every time.

Am I missing something really basic here?  I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: Try adding this to the page <%=Context.User.Identity.Name%> and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure what ActionLink overload you are using, here is what I think it should be: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "User", new { username = Context.User.Identity.Name }, new { })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what you should expect given that route.  You don't specify `username` in the route values dictionary but in the HTML attributes, so it takes the default from the route, `*`.  You should be using the signature that allows you to specify both the controller and the action as strings with additional route values in the dictionary.

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Identity.Name))
{
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "User" new { username = Context.User.Identity.Name }, null )</li>
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but then the asker says it works the first time, but not the second...

Comment: @Iain - I believe he must be confused.

Comment: tvanfosson, it works!!  I had to alter slightly to this though: <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", new { controller = "User", username = Context.User.Identity.Name},null)</li>      Strangely enough, though, it does work the first time as mentioned above... why?  I have no idea.  I broke it again and it still works the first time and not the next.    Thanks again tvanfosson, that was driving me nuts!